# What do -XX:-PrintGC and XX:-PrintGCDetails flags do?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I found the JVM flags [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp). Is there a more detailed explaination of what exactly they do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting this flags writes all the garbage collections made by the JVM to a log file (or stdout, but then it is less useful), and these can be analysed by tools such as the ones mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541832/know-of-any-java-garbage-collection-log-analysis-tools). Using this information you can fine tune your garbage collection configuration.

Comment: Using the above mentioned flags, is it possible to get the details of previous GC cycles (of time when these flags were not set)?

Comment: What do you mean by "previous GC cycles"?

Answer (score 9):

Rather on Sun's, use `-Xloggc:gc.log` to log to a file, `-verbose:gc` is also a common switch for this.

Also, ensure `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` and `-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps` (note the plus + sign).  The timestamp switch is redundant but good to include.

Comment: would you elaborate what -verbose:gc does? Since this answer is confusing for those who are trying to get some help. And upvoters must be only those who already know this.

Comment: @SyedAqeelAshiq seems a bit mean about the upvotes...but `-verbose:gc` is a mechanism to log Garbage Collection events in a verbose manner by which they can be parsed and post- or runtime-evalutated as to the required VM ergonomics. :-)

Comment: Purpose of SO is to provide high quality answers, to those who want to get some help. I was searching for PrintGC flag, but this answer confused me, and had to spend few hours finding difference between PrintGC and verbose:gc. Perhaps you should update your answer to mention the difference. And add complete sentences.

Comment: This does not answer the question - what is the difference between those two options?

Comment: `-verbose:gc` is an alias for `-XX:+PrintGC`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609051/difference-between-xxprintgc-and-verbosegc