# java app run much faster outside netbeans

Tags: java, performance, netbeans

When I run code inside NetBeans it is very slow. However, when I convert the code to a standalone application it runs 5 times faster. That is awkward because it won't let me test it as it will truly run on a mac. I'm using netbeans 8.

The application involves heavy memory usage. I think maybe, just maybe, netbeans is limiting the size of the heap. Anyway passed the `-Xmx2048m` flag to the program.

clue: when I build the software to an .app file, then go inside that app package and edit the .plist file, I manually add the line2:

```
<key>VMOptions</key>
<string>-Xmx1024m</string>
```

and that's the only way to make it run fast as I would like. And that is only as standalone, outside netbeans.

Comment: You're not saying how long it takes. If it's something like 1 ms vs 5 ms, then you're just wasting time by measuring the measurement error.  *** Use `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` and friends to find out more about memory; consider also printing [GC stats](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1815390/581205),

Answer (score 2):

You can change those parameters in netbeans by changing the Run Configuration (Right click your project and select Properties -> Run). It could also just be a simple case of the debugging enviroment overhead causing the slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to set the heap space used by the IDE itself.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSettingHeapSize

Answer (score 0):

If the application is SWING-related, there were a number of performance issues in the JDK that were [affecting Retina Macs](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029253). You should also try upgrading to a JDK release >8u40, where these problems were fixed.