# Erlang Garbage Collection logging

Tags: garbage-collection, erlang

Is there an Erlang equivalent of Java's `-XX:+PrintGC`? I have searched for "Erlang garbage collection logging" but most of what I find are explanations of how Erlang's GC works, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Can you explain what you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: [Erlang tracer](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#trace-3) can be registered for garbage collection events.  What information you're looking for?

Comment: @Reith this seems close to what I want, I'll play around with it. I want to know when the garbage collector runs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815390/what-do-xx-printgc-and-xx-printgcdetails-flags-do

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you look into [`observer`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/observer).

> Observer is a graphical tool for observing the characteristics of
> Erlang systems. The tool Observer displays system information, application supervisor trees, process information, ETS tables, Mnesia tables ..

There is a blog post about it [here](https://newrelic.com/blog/how-to-relic/memory-spikes-erlang). You can also find a getting started on [the official documentation](https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/observer/observer_ug.html).

If you prefer a CLI you can use [observer-cli](https://github.com/zhongwencool/observer_cli).

```
%% rebar.config
{deps, [observer_cli]}
%% erlang.mk
dep_observer_cli = hex 1.7.4
```