# Is there a way to monitoring garbage collector by terminal command line?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jmx

I need to monitor when the GC (specially full GC) is called. Can be on a specified application or hole JVM.

Note that must be a terminal command, jvisualvm and apps like does't suits my case.

I was thinking about use jmx, but also did not find any thing that suits me.

Note that one use of this command will be monitory when Cassandra'a GC runs. (automatic, of course)

Comment: Are you looking for a tool that does that or a programming way to do so?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1815390/2443502. This may be what you are looking for.