# solr - java heap space out of memory

Tags: java, tomcat, exception, solr

Can any one help me to find out the error cause in tomcat. i m using solr in it. starting it works fine. later i will raise  this error. after restarting it works fine. please help me to find out the error.

> Mar 7, 2011 10:36:47 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
>   SEVERE: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java
>   heap space    at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1068)     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:418)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processCommit(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:169)
>     at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:69)    at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
>     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1316)    at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:634)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:445)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: What does this question have to do with the "C#" tag?

Comment: How big is the heap space? The heap usage might be fine but the heap might be too small for it.

Comment: Ram size is 15.9 GB.After increasing the size of the heap also it throws error .. please help .. Advance Thanks...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to increase your memory

Either set the environment variable `JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx500m"` which means heap start size is 256 MB, max 512 MB. Or edit your catalina.bat or .sh and add this line there.

You have to play around with these values, some weeks ago I had an SOLR indexer job, about 2 GB of data, 700MB heap were required.

Answer (score 3):

start tomcat with an -Xmx1024m or some larger value to give tomcat more heap space.

Answer (score 3):

You can try lowering the default batchSize JDBC connection param in your dataSource definition.
DataImportHandler is designed to stream row one-by-one. It passes a fetch size value (default: 500) to Statement#setFetchSize which some drivers do not honor.

If you're using MsSQL you can add dataSource param responseBuffering="adaptive".

See here for more info:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerFaq

Answer (score 1):

you should definitely look into tuning your JVM.  to start with you should alter your JVM parameters to emit a Garbage Collection log and then use a tool to analyze that log.  this analysis will help you to pick sane values for your heap, and it will also allow you to gauge whether or not you really have a memory leak or just a heap tuning issue.  see this related question for some info on GC analysis tools:

[Analyze GC logs for Sun Hotspots, JVM 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839599/analyze-gc-logs-for-sun-hotspots-jvm-6/1841109#1841109)

Comment: after tunning the heap size also it throws error while indexing

Comment: i m having 16gb ram... what heap size can i set for maxium

Comment: it depends on if you are using a 32 or 64 bit jvm and if you are running on windows or linux.  32bit jvms on linux are typically constrained to the 4gb process ceiling, which means 3gb is about all you can allocate to the heap. this is further reduced on windows platform; 1.2gb is about all you can do for 32bit windows.  64bit jvms are pretty much unlimited for max heap size, but you will endure excessive GC times for really large heaps unless you tune your system accordingly.