# How to understand the Full GC log?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I currently see in PROD the following:

```
5429.779: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 13809K->0K(505216K)] [PSOldGen: 253802K->245481K(319488K)] 267612K->245481K(824704K) [PSPermGen: 70059K->70059K(118784K)], 0.5869143 secs] [Times: user=0.59 sys=0.00, real=0.59 secs]
```

I understand that A->B(C) means: A, before gc, B after gc, C heap without tenured and perm

What I don't understand is piece (outside all []s) which is `267612K->245481K(824704K)`. What does it refer to?

Answer (score 3):

It's the total of the generations, meaning the combined Heap Usage and total Heap Size in real memory (shown in braces).

In the given example, `[PSYoungGen: 13809K->0K(505216K)] [PSOldGen: 253802K->245481K(319488K)]  267612K->245481K(824704K)`:

```
13809K + 253802K = 267612K

0K + 245481K = 245481K

505216K + 319488K = 824704K
```

Answer (score 3):

May I advice you to use tools instead of manually reading logs.

Try [HPJmeter](https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=HPJMETER) tool

I find this tool best. Rest there are so many tools. Refer: [Know of any Java garbage collection log analysis tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541832/know-of-any-java-garbage-collection-log-analysis-tools)

Generally as per my experience, its always better to use tools like above which simply imports GC log file & gives detailed graphs for different generations. If you go for manual reading, then your time will be more invested in reading than performance analysis.