# Measuring time spent on GC

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

Suppose I am testing a Java server application. I know how much time it takes to finish the test. Now I'd like to know how much was spent on GC during that test. How can I do it?

Comment: I count the time to run end to end in tests, including GC times, and I only break it down when I want to performance tune it eg. with a memory profiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the `-Xloggc` and `-XX:-PrintGCTimeStamps` options when starting up your JVM.  I think it prints out how long garbage collection takes.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Answer (score 25):

> I guess that when GC (Garbage Collector) is working the application stops and resumes when GC finishes

I don't think that is a safe assumption. Are you sure the garbage collector is not working in parallel with your application code?

To measure the time spent in collecting garbage you can query the [Garbage Collector MXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html).

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    System.out.println("collectionTime = " + getGarbageCollectionTime());
}

private static long getGarbageCollectionTime() {
    long collectionTime = 0;
    for (GarbageCollectorMXBean garbageCollectorMXBean : ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {
        collectionTime += garbageCollectorMXBean.getCollectionTime();
    }
    return collectionTime;
}
```

Comment: This answer is super. I have being executing many tests over GC and the values provided by the `GarbageCollectorMXBean` are absolutely the same compared to the log written by the JVM args.

Comment: When does `getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()` return multiple mx beans?

Answer (score 4):

This performance metric is recorded by the JVM, and made accessible through JMX. For interactive monitoring, connect to the running JVM with JConsole, and in the "VM Summary" Tab it will say something like:

> Garbage collector: Name = 'Copy', Collections = 26, Total time spent = 0.183 seconds
>   Garbage collector: Name = 'MarkSweepCompact', Collections = 2, Total time spent = 0.168 seconds

You can also query JMX programatically.

Answer (score 4):

Another convenient solution is to run `jstat -gc` ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html)) against your process when your tests are done. That will give you nice aggregated output on exactly how much time has been spent in GC during the lifetime of your JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Enable garbage collection logs. As [documented](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html), you can use `-verbose:gc`, `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` and `-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps` flags. `-Xloggc` flag can be used to direct those to a file.

Resulting logs are human-readable, but for most benefit you probably want them to be run through an analyzer. Such tools are listed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541832/know-of-any-java-garbage-collection-log-analysis-tools).

Answer (score 1):

There are different GC algorithms that behave differently. I recently read a [good article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2012/121010-jvm-performance-optimization-garbage-collection.html) on the subject that I can recommend if you'd like to know more.

You can launch your application with the following command line options `-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails` and get information about GC.

Here's an example of the log message:

> 2012-12-17T03:02:15.590-0500: [GC [PSYoungGen: 40934K->2670K(29440K)]
>   48211K->14511K(73152K), 0.5745260 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.01,
>   real=0.58 secs]

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Steve McLeod's answer that uses [ManagementFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html), since Java 8 this can also be written in a single line using [Java streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
long collectionTime = ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans().stream().mapToLong(mxBean -> mxBean.getCollectionTime()).sum();
```

Comment: When does `getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()` return multiple mx beans?

Comment: I cannot test it at the moment, but I am pretty sure this happens if two different collectors are used for minor and major collections respectivly.