# How to get zGC allocation stall times from the JVM?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, zgc

How can I get the total allocation stall time due to zGC Garbage Collection in my Java application from the JVM (not the `gc.log`)?

I saw this interesting answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13915440/992432, but looking at the the docs for [GarbageCollectorMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.management/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html) there are only two methods, neither of which seems to differentiate between general time spent and time the Java application had to stop to GC:

> #### Method Summary
>
> long  `getCollectionCount()` -  Returns the total number of collections that have occurred.
>
> long `getCollectionTime()` - Returns the approximate accumulated collection elapsed time in milliseconds.

What I really want to know is the time spent as full allocation stalls due to GCs (note I do not care about [safepointed times](https://dzone.com/articles/java-runtime-performance-monitoring-gc-and-safepoi)). As this article says in Java Magazine:

> Many garbage collection algorithms have been tried and tested over the years, iteratively improving their performance. There are two common areas of performance for such algorithms
> The first is garbage collection throughput: How much of your
> application’s CPU time is spent performing garbage collection work
> rather than running application code? **The second is the delay
> created—that is, the latency of individual pauses.**

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.